# How do I unblock port on windows

Tags: http, connection, port, ports

How do I unblock a port on windows to get an http connection?

I have already tried opening the port but when I use a port checker it says the port is still closed.

Answer (score 5):

**Open TCP Port 80 (HTTP) in Windows Firewall:**

1. From the Windows Start menu, open **Control Panel**.
2. Select **Windows Firewall**.
3. Select **Advanced settings** in the left column of the Windows Firewall window.
4. Select **Inbound Rules** in the left column of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security window.
5. Select **New Rule** in the right column.
6. Select **Port** in the New Inbound Rule Wizard and then click Next.
   Note: Do not create a **Program rule** – you must create a **Port rule**.
7. Select which protocol this rule will apply to **TCP**, select **Specific local ports**, type port number **80**, and then click **Next**.
8. Select **Allow the connection** and then click **Next**.
9. Select when this rule applies (check all of them for the port to always stay open) and then click **Next**.
10. Give this rule a name and then click **Finish** to add the new rule.
    TCP Port 80 is now open and ready to be used.

**If You still find it blocked follow these steps:**

1. Open **cmd**
2. type **netstat -a -n -o**
3. find **TCP [the IP address]:[port number] .... #[target_PID]#**
4. **CTRL+ALT+DELETE** and choose "**start task manager**"

   Click on "**Processes**" tab

   Enable "**PID**" column by going to: **View > Select Columns > Check the box for PID**

   Find the **PID** of interest and "**END PROCESS**"

   Your port will be open now.

Answer (score 0):

I found it and the port 80 is blocked by "System" - "NT Kernel & system" and the orginal file name is ntoskrnl.exe on system32 directory. End task is disabled for this process.